# What are the steps to upload a java web application

Tags: java, glassfish

After a lot of work i manage to finish a java web aplication with netbeans using primefaces/glassfish server (it is a e-shop that we developed for a school project). I use xampp (mySql) in order to fiddle around with a database that i use in the web app.

My problem is that i have no idea on how to upload this to a server. What am i supposed to install on it ?, i dont even know what os to use :/ .  Im really bad at the "internet part" of this project and since this was my last school year i can not reach for my professor to ask him for help.

I know my question is vague but please help me to finish this project because it would help me a lot to find a job in the future.

I should also mention that i use a mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar .If im not wrong this allows me to send data throw a TCP connection right? My main problem is that im missing the Full picture ,I know how to write basic code in java , i know how to build the xhtml pages and how to bind them to the java code behind but other than that i dont get how the rest of this works.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: as i said im  bad at this. if you just post a generic link on "how to set up a Javaweb" i will not be able to follow . Im asking here ,on this forum because i want human answer. I need someone to post a 4-5 line explanation and like 8 bulletins on what to do like

*install linux

*Build and export your project.

*install glassfish standalone.

etc

The thinks google returns to me are like 400 pages of glassfish documentation and really hard to follow guides on how to do what i want. Of course i could waste the next month or so just reading and trying to figure out how everything comes together (witch i inevitably have to do)but i feel like im only 15 clicks away. I just want a practical answer.

Comment: If you google properly, you will find a lot of links for developing a web application using J2EE. [Here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html) is one that might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You need an application server to "upload" the code. Use tomcat, its simple and has plenty of documentation available.

If you are using XAMPP, you may be familiar with Apache Server, which runs , among other things PHP. For Java, you need application server to run the server side code.

It doesnt matter which OS you want to use, Java runs on all. You just need to download and install tomcat for the OS you want to run it on.

Please refer to http://tomcat.apache.org/

I must point out that there are many more Application servers which are available. Tomcat is one of the most popular for learning purpose.